# Objective-C GET Request - How to not freeze the UI, and wait for response?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm making a simple GET request using the following code:

```
NSString *urlStr = [@"http://192.168.1.107/Server.Mobile/test.ashx?rp="
                          stringByAppendingString:[rpText 
                               stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]                                                          
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                     timeoutInterval:100];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But, while performing it, I'm trying to show an UIAlertView, and then dismiss it when the request is complete.

I know how to show/hide the alert, but I can't manage to synchronize it with the request. The request freezes the UI, so when it is done the AlertView shows and hides instantly:

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please, wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];

// ... Perform get request...

[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

If I, on the other hand, assign the request to an async operation, like `dispatch_async`, I can't call the dismiss. It just doesn't close the AlertView

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please, wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // ... Perform get request...

    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
});
```

**How can I show the Alert, perform the request waiting for the response, and then close the Alert?**

I'm new to iOS development...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for `NSURLConnection` to operate in an asynchronous fashion. Create an `NSURLConnection` with the `initWithRequest:delegate:` initializer, passing yourself as delegate. Once the request has finished, you will receive a `connectionDidFinishLoading:` callback, from which you can update your UI.

Or better yet, use the new [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1) APIs to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

make a asynchronous network call. Easiest way with your existing code would be `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

```
NSString *urlStr = [@"http://192.168.1.107/Server.Mobile/test.ashx?rp="
                          stringByAppendingString:[rpText 
                               stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please, wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]                                                          
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                     timeoutInterval:100];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;


(^handler)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error);

handler = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    if(error == nil){
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    } else {
        // handle error
    }
};

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:handler];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is not the best way. But this code solve your problem:

```
     alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please, wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];

dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("makeRequest", nil), ^{

    NSString *urlStr = [@"http://192.168.1.107/Server.Mobile/test.ashx?rp="
                        stringByAppendingString:[rpText
                                                 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:100];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

    NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
    NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) that is a library that simplifies asynchronous requests. You can use this code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    // UPDATE YOUR UI HERE
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```